# Wifi occasionally unresponsive but VPN works

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

I have a strange networking issue in my house. Sometimes I find the wifi network slow or unresponsive, as if I'm in a dead spot. However, if I enable my VPN, I am able to use the network.

I have a broadband modem and router all-in-one from my ISP (Plusnet in UK). I also have two Belkin N300 wifi extenders deployed around the house, so my devices seem to show decent wifi signal strength everywhere.

My VPN server is a Raspberry Pi running OpenVPN, connected by ethernet cable directly to the router.

On various devices, such as my iPad, I sometimes see very slow response times (bordering on no response at all), which suggests that either the wifi connection is not working, or the router's connection to the internet is not working. However, if I connect to my VPN server, suddenly it all seems to be working fine, indicating that both the wifi connection and the router's internet are working.

How is this possible?

I assume there must be some misconfiguration somewhere, but I'm not sure what it could be. If you need more information to diagnose it, let me know in the comments and I'll try to add that information.

Note that this is an intermittent (although annoyingly frequent) problem, so the network is not completely broken.

Comment: One possibility is the DNS server of your ISP. Which DNS server is used by the VPN?

Comment: @harrymc The same DNS server is used both on and off the VPN - the router itself.

Comment: Do you connect to the VPN over wifi? If yes, could you detail the connection chain from your device to the VPN and internet? (To better understand your LAN architecture.)

Comment: Yes, I connect to the VPN over wifi (for some devices like my iPad there's no other choice). I think the connection chain is:  iPad --> N300 wifi extender --> router --> Raspberry Pi (VPN server)

Comment: Do you mean it's like:  iPad -> wifi extender -> router -> Raspberry Pi -> router -> internet? And this works better than: iPad -> wifi extender -> router -> internet?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: Sounds contrary to common sense. Perhaps you should search for firmware updates to the router and/or the extender (if such exists). Contact also your ISP (it's their router).